# Signalr 1.1.3 - IIS 7.5 - ports time_wait

Tags: iis, signalr

Is it possibile that a signalR hub opens lots of port on iis to handle connections with his clients?
Is it possible that this produce lots of TIME_WAIT (zombie connections?)?

IIS 7.5, it means that webSockets isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

through a tcp viewer i saw that signalr create 4/5 connections for each user on different port:
[OnConnected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWwMz.png);
When the client closes the connection (browser was closed or an exception was occurred) the state of connection changes in TIME_WAIT:
[OnDisconnected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WiKG.png);
After X seconds of TIME_WAIT all connections are deleted.